# Why does everything look so big in my app? IOS

Tags: ios, xcode

I was messing around with the launch screen in the target section, and now my app looks like this

[image]

I did revert everything back to normal but I have no idea why it still stays like that.

Comment: The black bars are a clear indication that your launch screen storyboard isn't setup properly.

Comment: It worked fine before, but how do I fix this? PS. Im not using storyboards

Comment: You must use a launch screen storyboard. You have no choice.

Comment: okay thank you @rmaddy